# In 2016 theme, how can I force all single attachment posts to use content-attachment.php rather than image.php?

Tags: templates

Using 2016. For Search and Archive and Index, all attachment posts use content-attachment to display the excerpt... as expected.

But when I go to the actual attachment, it uses the image.php template. How can I get the post to use the same template as in archive or index or search? (content-attachment)?

Comment: Assuming you're referring to the [TwentySixteen theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentysixteen/), it doesn't have a `content-attachment.php` file. You could rename the image.php to something WordPress doesn't recognize and see what it falls back to. See the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) for more information.

Comment: Right. I added a content-attachment.php and it works fine for archive, search, index. But for accessing the full post, it wants to use image.php. And if I remove that, it falls back to page.php. I was just curious how to get it to use my content-attachment.php to avoid having duplicate code.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple things you could do. If we follow the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) you could rename your `content-attachment.php` file to `attachment.php` and remove `image.php`. This will ensure that the image view will fallback to `attachment.php`.

---

If you want to use `content-attachment.php` then you could use the `template_include` hook to tell WordPress to load in which situation.

```
/**
 * Tell WordPress to load a specific template under specific circumstances.
 *
 * @param String $template_path
 *
 * @return String $template_path
 */
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template_path ) {

    if( false !== strpos( $template_path, 'image.php' ) ) {

        // Path to your PHP file, relative to the twentysixteen theme (or child theme)
        // This would mean `content-attachmetn.php` is in the twentysixteen root, with page.php and singe.php
        $template_path = get_template_part( 'content-attachment' );
    }

    return $template_path;

} );
```